# Grails Mocking: Supply any argument to demand closure

Tags: grails, groovy, mocking

I have a service that I'm trying to test. Inside this service is another `UserAPIService` that I want to mock. To mock it I'm doing the following:

```
    given:
    def userAPIServiceMock = mockFor(UserAPIService)
    userAPIServiceMock.demand.createUser { def apiToken, firstname, lastname, email -> return true 
    }
    service.userAPIService = userAPIServiceMock.createMock()
```

In the demand closure, I don't really care what arguments are passed to the `createUser` method. Is there a way I can say "regardless of the arguments passed to the createUser method, return true."

In other words, how can I change

```
userAPIServiceMock.demand.createUser { def apiToken, firstname, lastname, email -> return true
```

to

```
userAPIServiceMock.demand.createUser { [any arguments] -> return true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with Spock.

The syntax is as follows:

```
mock.method(*_) >> { args -> true }
```

Not sure how your Grails service needs to be mocked, but here's a full, general example in Spock:

```
  interface Service {
    boolean hej( String s, boolean b, char c )
  }

  class ExampleSpec extends Specification {

  def "mock method with any number of args"() {
    when:
    def mock = Mock( Service )
    mock.hej(*_) >> { args -> true }

    then:
    mock.hej( 'hi', true, 'a' as char ) == true
  }
}
```

`args` is a `List` containing the actual arguments, which you can inspect in the closure and return the appropriate value.